# How to import numpy as standard user from server?

Tags: python, numpy

I installed `python, numpy, scipy` as super user in server and I can import them  without any errors. However, standard users (who connect with ssh) can not import them. 
How to fix it so that standard users can import them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like your $PATH isn't pointing to those executables.

try running the following as root and then as as user

```
echo $PATH
which python
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

this will tell you which python installation you are using and where it is looking for installed python files.

It sounds like your user accounts are not pointing at the same python setup. Its best with python to only use root to update the system packages as most distros require specific python versions for some of their internal tools.

Have a look at Virtualenv installations for your user accounts , this way you can have a custom setup for each user that will not conflict, its also easier to migrate that user to other machines as the python setup will be entirely in its homedir.

Comment: I checked all paths and rewrite to make them similar as super user's bashrc. Interesting thing is standard user could import unum,docutils etc.. However they couldn't import numpy. So I changed permissions on /usr/local/.. and installed numpy in python-virtualenv for standard users. It may not be the best solution but now it works. Thanks for your time.

Comment: virtualenv is generally the best way for user python installs , it pays dividends later when you need to migrate or upgrade, just create new user with upgrades and switch back and forth at will.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that since you are running Ubuntu, your standard users'
OS has Python installed or that the users can install Python if it is not already installed. Add the import paths for numpy and scipy on the server at the beginning of your Python script,

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/numpy")
import numpy
sys.path.append("/path/to/scipy")
import scipy
```

Comment: its a really bad idea to hack sys.path inside a script if you ever want to move it around or run more than one script , its a better to configure the shell to provide the right paths with PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I disagree because it is a pain to ask all the standard users in the question to keep changing PYTHONPATH instead of making it easier for them by making the Python script do the heavy lifting for them. I guess following your logic I could retaliate by downvoting you (if that was your simultaneously cast downvote) but instead I will suffice by saying I disagree with your comment. Also I wouldn't downvote you because it was a very interesting comment, even though I don't agree with it.

Comment: the problem here is that the shell is not configured , fixing it in your script breaks portability for important things like testing , development and staging. I'm here to share not for spite.